# ODI using ODIOutFil feature to create a file

Tags: oracle10g

I am a new in a team and I am training on ODI 10 as I am beginner.
I started by creating a simple job that evaluates a value and according the result it will create a file in a folder in local.
I keep receiving and error saying 'FileNotFound: C:...  (Access is denied)'
I choose the folder on the local machine C:...

I affect to that folder an acces to Everyone with Full control, and no change from oDI I keep receiveing the same error

I don't know how could I resolve it. Thanks for helping.

I try to write a simple words in a file within the folder I created on my C:... by using ODI 10, I use the feature OdiOutFile
I expected to see a file within the path I specified with the result as mentionned in the ODI job